# Is there a function like millis() of Arduino in python?

Tags: python, time

Is there a function like millis() of Arduino (not delay() function) in python?
I want to stop a specific part of program for a while ,but not the whole program.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html

Answer (score 1):

Try using `utime` functions

https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/library/utime.html

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using

```
import time
seconds_to_sleep=1
time.sleep(seconds_to_sleep)
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is a little unclear, since `millis()` just gives you the time since the program started execution, but you want to pause parts of your program.

A Python script runs as a single-threaded process, if you want to block a specific part of your program while not blocking the rest, you first need to start up additional threads and/or processes and split your logic across them.

- https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html

AFAIK there's no builtin "time since startup" variable (but I might be wrong, of course, happy to learn otherwise), I would add a `time.time()` call to your `__main__` block:

```
import time


def main():
    global time_of_startup

    # ... lots of code here ... 

    time_since_start = time.time() - time_of_startup


if __name__ == "__main__":
    time_of_startup = time.time()
    main()
```